# How would I be able to open a .msc extension and "Click" within the .msc file using powershell

Tags: powershell

So, I'm new to powershell scripting in windows.  How would one open a .msc file using powershell and be able to do the equivalent of a "Click" within the .msc

Answer (score 0):

Powershell (PS) and MMC are two technologies with fundamentally different goals. PS is about automation. MMC is about traditional GUI goals (ease of use, display of information, guided tasks, etc.) You will be much better off using PS modules that implement the functionality of the MSC you have in mind and bypassing MMC altogether.

The results will be more robust, much easier for someone else to understand, and easier to maintain. Versus sending keystrokes and mouse clicks, the amount of time to implement via PS modules may take longer at first, but if you do it more than 3 or so times will probably be quicker. There is sometimes a fair amount of pain with sending key strokes to get the timing right. And there is a lot of pain involved with sending key strokes if an error occurs in the MSC. The first is a non-issue if using PS modules. The second is straightforward to handle if using PS modules.

For example, most `certmgr.msc` functionality is built into PS with the "cert" provider. You can `chdir` into the `cert:` drive and view, copy, delete, and modify certificates in the cert store.

That said you can implement sending keystrokes from PS to another app, in a pretty straight forward way using `WshShell.SendKeys` (google it). Hopefully you MSC has the right set of accelerator keys defined to do the task you have in mind.

If you really need mouse clicks, I suggest this [site](http://powershell.com/cs/blogs/tips/archive/2014/05/06/automation-via-keystroke-and-mouse-click.aspx) and the referenced WASP module.